# How do I search all my open Chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, search

Assume I'm running Google Chrome with dozens of open browser tabs.

How can I search the text of the tab titles?  As an example, assume I want to find the string: "vul"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to search all open Chrome tabs...

###### 1. List your open Chrome tab titles with a search-box...

- {Windows}: Control-Shift-A

- {MacOS}: Command-Shift-A


2. Use the search box on the upper right-hand side of a Chrome Window to find Chrome tab titles... This example searches open tab titles for "vul"

[image: Google Chrome search box]

Comment: I needed to know this 10 years ago given how many tabs I usually have open in my browser. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For simple searching in all the Headlines of the tabs, chrome has a inbuild functionality, Ctrl+Shift+A. It is doing exacly what you asked for.

However, for my purposes it was not sufficient, because if you have multiple tabs of different parts of the same website open, the search results will be the same.

I wrote a Plugin for Chrome to better fit this task. It has a shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+F) for opening and it searches full-text in all tabs. Try it yourself if you want.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supersearch/ijajhcdgklelnpmjodhfhjooiljfhdpl?hl=en-US

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness (i.e. addressing similar needs on other browsers), here's the link for info on doing the same on Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-open-tabs-firefox

NB: I just joined the community -- rules recommend entering answers first! (before I can enter a comment on another answer, or even UPvote another person's answer). I wanted to UPvote Mike Pennington's answer (or provide a complement on it in a comment); that answer is something I needed to know 20 years ago!

Comment: Thats because you are not trusted yet and comments cant be downvoted.

Comment: Sure, I understand (some of) the rationale.  But at least let a new member "Upvote" some else's answer? What would be the harm in allowing that? Anyway, on with the rules.